# storing a pointer to a member function

Tags: c++

I'm wrapping an existing C API to make it easier to use in my VS2008 C++ program. The C API is expecting an array of "TABLE_ENTRY" structures that include a function pointer as in the code below.

But, I'm having difficulty storing a pointer to a member function in the function pointer.
Can anybody point out what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks,
PaulH

My code looks basically like this:

```
struct TABLE_ENTRY; // forward decl

typedef int (WINAPI *MYPROC )(DWORD msg, TABLE_ENTRY* entry);

struct TABLE_ENTRY {
    const char* description;
    DWORD value;
    MYPROC callback;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : description( "Some Description" ),
                some_value( 1 )
    {
    };

    int MyProc( DWORD msg, TABLE_ENTRY* my_entry )
    {
        return 0;
    };

    TABLE_ENTRY* operator*()
    {
        entry_.description = description.c_str();
        entry_.value = some_value;
        // error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' to 'MYPROC'
        entry_.callback = boost::bind< int >( &MyClass::MyProc, this );
        return &entry_;
    };

    TABLE_ENTRY entry_;
    std::string description;
    DWORD some_value;
};

class MyClassCollection
{
public:
    TABLE_ENTRY* GetTable()
    {
        // is this okay or is it Evil & wrong?
        return ( &collection_.front() )->operator*();
    };

    void Add( MyClass& my_class )
    {
        collection_.push_back( my_class );
    }
private:
    std::vector< MyClass > collection_;
};

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    MyClass class1;
    MyClass class2;

    MyClassCollection collection;
    collection.Add( class1 );
    collection.Add( class2 );

    TABLE_ENTRY* table = collection.GetTable();
    TABLE_ENTRY entry1 = table[ 0 ]; // should be class1's table
    TABLE_ENTRY entry2 = table[ 1 ]; // should be class2's table

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: instead of `MYPROC`, you want to use type `boost::function<int(DWORD msg, TABLE_ENTRY* entry)>`;

Comment: Your use of operator overloading is evil, by the way.

Comment: @Johannes: and then give it to C API?

Comment: Also, sticking these into a `std::vector` is dangerous, since you bind the function to `this` of the vector elements. If the vector needs to reallocate during addition of elements, all pointers you previously gained or bound are made invalid.

Comment: @GMan - Is it evil because it's obscure and difficult to understand or Evil in the sense that it won't work in some situation? Can you be more specific?

Comment: It's evil because that operator is intended to dereference something. There's no reason to make it an operator, it doesn't make it's usage any easier. Use member functions, and only use operators when it really makes sense, like using `operator+` to add two vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::bind` creates a ***functor***, i.e. an instance of a class that implements `operator()`. This is not interchangeable with plain C function pointers.

Comment: The solution being don't use `boost::bind`. You have use a vanilla function pointer, not even a member function pointer (which requires an instance of a class to call on.) This is an unfortunate thing of statically typed languages, especially C (which the API is), where we can't even use templates to at least get a bit more generality (such a with `boost::bind`). You'll have to make a static function that somehow delegates the call to the "real" procedure.

Comment: The question is, however, how to bind the `this` pointer. The static functon pointer has no way to know on what object to invoke on. I bet some of the fields in that entry can serve for this, tho :)

Comment: Most C callback APIs have a notion of *closure* or *private data* to get back at, say, struct for specific device in a device driver. I wonder what that `description` field is for ...

Comment: One dirty hack is to `reinterpret_cast` the address of the callback `entry` parameter to address of containing class. **disclaimer:** table entry must be the first member of the class; the class must not be polymorphic or even derived from anything; this might not work on your particular compiler; don't try it at home, etc.

Comment: @litb: Indeed, a very vague "somehow" in my original comment. :P Nikolai is right, most if not all Win32 callbacks provide some way of getting unique data from it. This usually makes for a good key into a `map` (or even better, `unordered_map`) to find the corresponding object. Then just forward the parameters into the actual function.

Comment: @litb - You're correct. The API does include a parameter I can use to pass a "this" pointer and end up with the functionality I wanted.

My operator*() is broken, but I'll start a new question for that one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
typedef int (WINAPI *MYPROC )(DWORD msg, TABLE_ENTRY* entry);
```

...needs to be this:

```
typedef int (WINAPI MyClass::*MYPROC )(DWORD msg, TABLE_ENTRY* entry);
```

There were a whole bunch of other problems, but I think what you were asking about was your member function pointer, so I don't need to comment on the rest.

Comment: Well, what the OP obviously wants is to convert former into the latter by "binding" the `this` parameter.

Comment: @AndreyT: You might be right, but that's not how I read the OP.  I gathered from the title of the post that the problem was storing a pointer to a member function, and PaulH was simply using bind to accomplish that goal.  Not a question about bind so much as a question about member function pointers.  But again, you could be right.